# Issues with Rest API authentication using oAuth2 using Python

Tags: python, api, authentication, curl

Im trying to use a Rest Api that has oAuth2 authentication using a generated apikey in the admin console of a portal to retrieve an acccess token, which is then to be used for all requests. In the documentation they provide an example request for retrieving the acceess token using curl, which looks like so:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://exampleurl.com/oauth2/token \
  -u apitoken:abcsdsadssfsagasagasgasgasgasg \
  --data grant_type=client_credentials
```

Using this script is working and I get an access token as a response.
Now I am working in python and am not able to get the same results there so far. The code I have been writing looks like this:

```
import requests 
headers={'apitoken': 'abcsdsadssfsagasagasgasgasgasg'}
data={'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
try:
    r = requests.post('https://exampleurl.com/oauth2/token', headers=headers, data=data)
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    raise SystemExit(err)
```

Running this script gives me a 401 HTTP error "Unauthorized for url".
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By using `-u` option of the `curl` command, you are setting the header `'Authorization: Basic your_credentials'` where `your_credentials` part is the base64 encoded version of the string `apitoken:abcsdsadssfsagasagasgasgasgasg`. So, in Python, you can either set the Authorization header as:

```
import base64
your_credentials = "{}:{}".format('apitoken', 'abcsdsadssfsagasagasgasgasgasg')
your_credentials_base64 = base64.b64encode(your_credentials.encode())
headers={'Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(your_credentials_base64)}
data={'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
try:
    r = requests.post('https://exampleurl.com/oauth2/token', headers=headers, data=data)
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    raise SystemExit(err)
```

or, you can use [requests.auth](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication)

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
data={'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
try:
    r = requests.post('https://exampleurl.com/oauth2/token', data=data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('apitoken', 'abcsdsadssfsagasagasgasgasgasg'))
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    raise SystemExit(err)
```